# Raspbian - problem installing mplayer-gui

Tags: raspbian, apt

I am starting with Raspberry pi 2 (Raspbian). I am trying to install mplayer with mplayer-gui.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer mplayer-gui alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio mpg123
```

All packages install OK, but then this message appears:

```
seaudio mpg123
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mplayer2' instead of 'mplayer'
E: Unable to locate package mplayer-gui
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a package named `mplayer-gui`. There is a package named `smplayer` that gives a GUI to the mplayer program. Try `apt-get install smplayer`.

As a side note, I have not found any video player that could playback videos reliably except `omxplayer` which was built with the Pi's GPU in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I am a newbie and I get the tip from this link https://rasspberrypi.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/audio-and-video-playback-on-raspberry-pi/.

Comment: That was posted in 2012. It may have been packaged differently at that time.  Does installing smplayer work for you? It is basically the equivalent.

Comment: Oh yes, I will try it. May you tell me what is the message "Note, selecting 'mplayer2' instead of 'mplayer'" in my question?

Comment: Is there a frontend  gui app to omxplayer?

Comment: mplayer2 is a modified version or fork of the original mplayer that fixed a lot of bugs and the package manager gets that one instead of the buggy one. See this: http://ubuntuguide.net/install-mplayer2-another-mplayer-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: Google is your friend :-) There are frontends for it created in python and other languages like tboplayer but they are not available via apt-get AFAIK.